# Why .Concat method's return value type looks a bit weird: System.Linq.Enumerable+(...)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, concatenation

I have 2 instances:

> ```
>      foo and bar
> ```

Their types are:

```
 foo.GetType().ToString()
```

returns:
**System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.MyClass]**

```
bar.GetType().ToString()
```

returns:
**System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.MyClass]**

When I concatanate them:

```
var foobar = foo.Concat(bar);
```

The GetType() returns 
**System.Linq.Enumerable+d__71`1[MyNameSpace.MyClass]**

**Question**:
What does this mean? Should not it be IEnumerable ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't confuse the declared return type and the actual type of the returned value. `Concat` is declared to return `IEnumerable<T>`, but it actually returns an instance of a concrete type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. `GetType` returns the concrete type, not the declared return type.

As for the weird name, `Concat` is implemented with an [iterator block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx), and iterator blocks are transformed by the compiler into types with names such as `Enumerable+d__71` that implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: so if a return value of IEnumerable<MyNameSpace.MyClass> is expected and if I "return foo.Concat(bar);" that should be fine? No need to "return foo.Concat(bar).ToArray();" Am I correct?

Comment: @pencilCake - you are correct, the `.ToArray()` is not needed. The thing to note is that if you did call `.ToArray()` it would iterate at that moment and put all the results into a new `MyClass[]` array. Without the `.ToArray()` call, execution of the iterator is differed.

Comment: Out of context question maybe but if a WCF service returns a deferred query, does this mean that the client will fail as it will not really recieve the query results but a deferred query instead?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, Thanks! Your answer really helped me to get the point.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Thomas' answer, note that the "`1" portion of the name indicates the number of generic arguments. The type for each generic argument follows in the brackets "[...]".